# Multiple floating point input from keyboard

Tags: c, input, scanf, floating

I am reading multiple floating numbers from a single scanf output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{ float a,b,c;
  float d,rot1,rot2;
  scanf("%f%f%f ", &a, &b, &c);
  d = sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c);
  rot1 = (-b-d)/(2*a);
  rot2 = (-b+d)/(2*a);
  printf("%f %f", rot1, rot2);
  return 0;
}
```

It takes 4 inputs; however, I want to take only 3 inputs for the addresses of variables a, b and c. I don't know which variable it takes the extra input from. When I wrote code for taking input for 2 variable, then it takes 3 inputs.

Comment: You need to read the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and test the resulting item count

Comment: It is not waiting for four inputs, it is waiting for three followed by whitespace;  <newline> counts as whitespace.

Comment: @Clifford  `scanf("%f%f%f "...` 1) read 3 FP inputs, 2) reads and tosses white-space and then 3) reads a non-white-space character.  Upon receiving that `char`, it is put back into `stdin` for the next input function.  Then `scanf()` returns.  Certainly acts like waiting for 4 inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf("%f%f%f ", &a, &b, &c);
             ^
```

Remove this extra space after `%f`.

**Note** - You should make sure that expression in `sqrt` does not evaluate to negative number. You probably want to avoid that condition.